# Solving an elliptic equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations

First, my question is :

> $U$ : bounded, open w/ $\partial U$ : $C^{1}$.
>
> Let $Lu=-\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\left(a^{ij}u_{x_{i}}\right)_{x_{j}}$ where
>   $a^{ij}\in L^{\infty}\left(U\right)$ : symmetric and uniformly
>   elliptic.
>
> For each $f\in L^{2}\left(U\right)$, consider $(*)\begin{cases} Lu-\lambda u=f & U\\ u=0 & \partial U \end{cases}$. Then I want to
>   find a solution or solutions of this elliptic equation with drichlet
>   boundary.

My approach is : Since $L^{2}(U)$ is separable, there are eigenvalues
$\left\{ \lambda_{k}\right\} $ organizing $0<\lambda_{1}\leq\lambda_{2}\leq\cdots$
and corresponding countable orthonormal basis(eigenfunctions) $\left\{ \phi_{k}\right\} _{k=1}^{\infty}$
which is in turn to be eigenfunctions of $L$. Then $L\phi_k=\lambda_{k}\phi_k$.

First, consider $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $L$. Then $N\left(L-\lambda I\right)$
is a trivial set.

Then $u$ and $f$ can be written as following : $f=\sum\left(f,\phi_{k}\right)_{L^{2}}\phi_{k}$,
and $u=\sum a_{k}\phi_{k}$.

If we product $\phi_{k}$ on $\left(*\right)$, then $\left(f,\phi_{k}\right)=((L-\lambda I)a_{k}\phi_{k},\phi_{k})=a_{k}\left((L-\lambda I\right)\phi_{k},\phi_{k})$.
(I think this part is wrong)
So $a_{k}={\displaystyle \frac{(f,\phi_{k})}{\left((L-\lambda I)\phi_{k},\phi_{k}\right)}}$.

So finally we can write $u={\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(f,\phi_{k})}{\left((L-\lambda I)\phi_{k},\phi_{k}\right)}\phi_{k}}$.

Next, suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $L$, and WLOG, let $\lambda=\lambda_{1}=\lambda_{2}\cdots=\lambda_{l}$.

Then $\phi_{1},\phi_{2},\cdots,\phi_{l}$ spans the $N\left(L-\lambda I\right)$.

Then like above, $u={\displaystyle \sum_{k=l+1}^{\infty}\frac{(f,\phi_{k})}{\left((L-\lambda I)\phi_{k},\phi_{k}\right)}\phi_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{l}a_{k}\phi_{k}}$for
any $a_{1},a_{2}\cdots,a_{l}\in\mathbb{R}$.

From alternative, If $f\in$Image$\left(L-\lambda I\right)$, above
form is the solutions.

If not, there is no solution.

---

I don't make sure whether my proof is correct or not. Tell me some comments

Comment: I prefer the notation $L_u = -\sum_{i,j} \partial_{x_i} (a^{ij} \partial_{x_i} u)$. And you mean $\lambda_k \to \infty$. Then I don't see why you think $a_{k}={\displaystyle \frac{(f,\phi_{k})}{\left((L-\lambda I)\phi_{k},\phi_{k}\right)}}=\frac{(f,\phi_{k})}{\lambda_k}$ is wrong. The operator $T  v = \sum_k \frac{1}{ \lambda_k \|\phi_k\|^2}(v,\phi_k) \phi_k$ is a bounded operator (by your uniformly elliptic assumption) and clearly $T = L^{-1}$.

Comment: And the most important : what are you trying to show ? What you wrote is mainly tautologic ($L$ is unbounded positive and we can apply the spectral theorem to its inverse that you assumed to be compact and positive).

Comment: @user1952009 As you says, my one is fool... Why I was thinking that is wrong is $((L−λI)ϕ_{k},\phi_{l})=0$ is not true.

Comment: @user1952009 that problem need me to find a solution(or solution) explicitly(I guess) so I wrote the solution as a infinite sum with a ONB(orthonomal basis).

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Your assumption is that $L^{-1}$ is a compact  positive operator so you can apply the spectral theorem to it, see [chapter 6 there](http://www.oulu.fi/sites/default/files/content/files/spectral.pdf)

Comment: @user1952009 the spectral theorem gives us such eigenvalue should converge to 0. But mine is not. And as I wrote above, the solution can be written as $u=∑a_{k}ϕ_{k}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @user1952009 Oh do you mean since I consider $L^{-1}$ the eigenvalues should converge to $\infty$! Yes right. haha.. And how can I get $((L−λI)ϕ_{k},ϕ_{l})=0$?