# Has a unique solution for the elliptic equation over special case $\mu>-\lambda_1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations

My question is :

> Let $\mu=\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\} $. Consider  $$\left(*\right)\begin{cases} -\triangle u+\mu u=f & U\\ u=0 & \partial U. 
> \end{cases} $$
>   Define 
>   $$
> \lambda_{1}=\inf_{u\in H_{0}^{1}}\frac{\int_{U}|Du|^{2}\ dx}{\int_{U}u^{2}\ dx}
> $$ If $\mu>-\lambda_{1}$, want to prove that $\left(*\right)$ has a unique
>   weak solution $u\in H_{0}^{1}\left(U\right)$ for each $f\in
> > L^{2}\left(U\right)$.

I know the Lax-Milgram theorem and some existence theorem in Chapter
6, Evans.

If I let 
$$
B[u,v]=\int_{U}-\triangle u\cdot v+\mu uv\ dx,
$$
then 
$$
B[u,v]=\int_{U}Du\cdot Dv\ dx+\mu\int_{U}uv\ dx.
$$
To show the assumption on Lax-Milgram theorem, clearly it satisfies
symmetry and uniform ellipticity. And readily, I proved that 
$$
|B[u,v]\leq\alpha\|u\|_{H_{0}^{1}}\|v\|_{H_{0}^{1}}.
$$
So, $B[u,u]\geq\beta\|u\|_{H}^{2}$ is left to me.

For this, 
$$
B[u,u]=\int_{U}|Du|^{2}+\mu\int_{U}u^{2}>\int_{U}|Du|^{2}-\lambda_{1}\int_{U}u^{2}\geq0.
$$

This one never gives me anyting.

How can I go further? Or, do I have to take other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TrialAndError's answer is almost correct but it gives an estimate with the wrong norm.

Note that there's nothing to do if $\mu \geq 0$. In the case $-\lambda_1 < \mu < 0$ the last line of your calculations can be slightly improved: decompose $1$ as $\frac{-\mu}{\lambda_1} + \frac{\lambda_1+\mu}{\lambda_1}$ to obtain 
$$ B[u,u]=\frac{\lambda_1+\mu}{\lambda_1} \int_{U}|Du|^{2} - \mu \left( \frac{1}{\lambda_1} \int_{U}|Du|^{2} - \int_{U}u^{2} \right) \geq \frac{\lambda_1+\mu}{\lambda_1} \int_{U}|Du|^{2}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Using your definition of $\lambda_1$, and assuming $\mu > -\lambda_1$,
\begin{align}
    \langle -\Delta f+\mu f,f\rangle & = \|Df\|^2+\mu\|f\|^2 \\
               & \ge \lambda_1\|f\|^2+\mu\|f\|^2 \\
                & = (\lambda_1+\mu)\|f\|^2 = \epsilon\|f\|^2,
\end{align}
where $\epsilon = \mu+\lambda_1 > 0$.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Could you check this for me? : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050707/solving-an-elliptic-equation